# Bulk insert with primary key Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to bulk insert file data into the table with primary key id column but I get this error.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkDataLoad]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RecordLine] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkDataLoad] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query:

```
truncate table WorkDataLoad

BULK INSERT WorkDataLoad
   FROM 'D:\NPfiles\TS082114.trn'
   WITH (
        TABLOCK,
        KEEPIDENTITY
   )
```

Error

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: and the error `Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.` - is the file properly terminated? what type of file is this .trn file?

Comment: is it a text file with sql commands or binary sql server transaction log?

Comment: Its transaction file if I replace file with text file same error occured

Comment: how did you obtain this `trn` file? Is it compatible with the formats listed in BULK INSERT documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx What does it look like (can you paste several rows?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your table as it is and create this VIEW (select everything except the ID(Primary Key) column)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VWWorkDataLoad]
AS
SELECT RecordLine
FROM [dbo].[WorkDataLoad];
```

Now **BULK INSERT** should then look like:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[VWWorkDataLoad] FROM 'D:\NPfiles\TS082114.trn' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

After running this statement you can check your table it should be having records with primary key. Hope this helps, it worked for me.